# If statement that checks if number has the expected number of digits

Tags: python

So i have to write a code that checks if personal number has 13 digits,if it has more or less it must raise ValueError,so i tried smth like this but it isnt working as intended

```
def jmbg(self,value):
    if len(str(value)) < 13 and len(str(value)) > 13:
        raise ValueError("Personal number must have 13 digits!")
    self.__jmbg = value
```

Comment: Your `and` should be `or`. How could a number be *both* less than 13 and greater than 13? Also why not just directly `if len(str(value)) != 13`

Comment: _but it isnt working as intended_ Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No number is less than *and* larger than 13. You want

```
if len(str(value)) < 13 or len(str(value)) > 13:
```

or, even simpler:

```
if len(str(value)) != 13:
```